# Sum specific values in Excel and display in Message Box?

Tags: vba, excel, vbscript

I have an Excel which has all list of marks in C Column.
I need a message box which should calculate sum of those marks and should display me while closing Excel (or) it's ok if it shows me when I click any shortcut key.
I have tried using below code but it does not work:

```
 Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
    Dim answer As Integer
    answer = MsgBox("Do want to see the total?", vbYesNo + vbQuestion, "Total")

        If answer = vbYes Then
          Range("G1").Value = Application.Sum(Range(Cells(3, 2), Cells(3, 3000)))
    Else
        'do nothing
    End If
    End Sub
```

Comment: Your columns and rows are backwards in your `cells` reference.  It should be `Cells(2,3), Cells(3000,3)`.

Answer (score 0):

What if you do

```
If answer = vbYes Then
  msgbox(Application.Sum(Range(Cells(2,3), Cells(3000,3)))
End If
```

(I switched your `Cells()` numbers around, since you want Column C, not row 3.)